# Unable to download file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to download a file which is in my local machine. Whenever I am clicking on download link, it's giving URL in browser as unsafe:http://localhost:8080/MYOB_Fabric/%7B%7B

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table class="table2" border=1 frame=void rules=rows>
        <tr>
            <th colspan=3>Transaction Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <th>Hash</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactionDetails ">
                <td><a  ng-href={{ fileUrl }} download="logFile.txt">{{ transaction.Hash }}</a></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Js code:

```
var appHlVl = angular.module('hlfabric', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
appHlVl.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(|blob|):/);
    }]);

appHlVl.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope,$http,$window,$sce) {
    var txtfileURL = '/home/rajasekhar/peer-log.txt';
    $http.get(txtfileURL, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    .then(function success(response) {
        var file = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: 'text/plain'
        }),
        url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
        $scope.fileUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url.createObjectURL(file));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-href="{{fileUrl}}" target="_blank">{{ transaction.Hash }}</a>
```

or app.config file put this line

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
```

Comment: target="_blank" it will open next tab, you put target="_self" it will open it same page

Comment: I am not facing issue with "target" attribute. I am unable to download local file.

Comment: fileurl contain path of localfile are not means fileurl="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS7VE_YDzLkWX504oXOjLdZwqeatfr7654-kRfG_zyh2_n6GPZvtG9fC82z"

Comment: put compile provider in /^\s*(https?|file|tel):

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|tel):/);
}]);
```